# finding the earliest occurrence in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running into trouble with this: I need to find the first time a user clicks on an email (variable sending) and put a one in that respective row when it occurs.

The dataset has several thousand users (hashed) who click a part of an email in a newsletter. I tried to group them by the sending, hash and then find the earliest date, but could not make it work.

So I went for a little nasty solution, which, however returns strange thing:

My dataset (relevant variables):

```
>>> clicks[['datetime','hash','sending']].head()

             datetime                              hash  sending
0 2016-11-01 19:13:34  0b1f4745df5925dfb1c8f53a56c43995        5
1 2016-11-01 10:47:14  0a73d5953ebf5826fbb7f3935bad026d        5
2 2016-10-31 19:09:21  605cebbabe0ba1b4248b3c54c280b477        5
3 2016-10-31 13:42:36  d26d61fb10c834292803b247a05b6cb7        5
4 2016-10-31 10:46:30  48f8ab83e8790d80af628e391f3325ad        5
```

There is 6 sending rounds, the `datetime` is `datetime64[ns]`.

My way of doing it is as follows:

```
clicks['first'] = 0

for hash in clicks['hash'].unique():
    t = clicks.ix[clicks.hash==hash, ['hash','datetime','sending']]
    part = t['sending'].unique()

    for i in part:
        temp = t.ix[t.sending == i,'datetime']
        clicks.ix[t[t.datetime == np.min(temp)].index.values,'first']=1
```

First of all, I dont think it is very pythonic, and is quite slow. But mostly it returns a weird type! There are `0.0` and `1.0` values, but I cannot work with them:

```
    >>> type(clicks.first)
    <type 'instancemethod'>

>>> clicks.loc[clicks.first==1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/air/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1296, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
  File "/Users/air/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1467, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/air/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 93, in _get_label
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/air/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1749, in xs
    loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/air/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 156, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3977)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 373, in pandas.index.Int64Engine._check_type (pandas/index.c:7634)
KeyError: False
```

----- UPDATE: ------

```
  INSTALLED VERSIONS
    ------------------
    commit: None
    python: 2.7.12.final.0
    python-bits: 64
    OS: Darwin
    OS-release: 15.6.0
    machine: x86_64
    processor: i386
    byteorder: little
    LC_ALL: None
    LANG: en_US.UTF-8

    pandas: 0.18.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) where compare values with `minimal` and output is boolean - need cast to `int` `0` and `1` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
clicks = pd.DataFrame({'hash': {0: '0b1f4745df5925dfb1c8f53a56c43995', 1: '0a73d5953ebf5826fbb7f3935bad026d', 2: '605cebbabe0ba1b4248b3c54c280b477', 3: '0b1f4745df5925dfb1c8f53a56c43995', 4: '0a73d5953ebf5826fbb7f3935bad026d', 5: '605cebbabe0ba1b4248b3c54c280b477', 6: 'd26d61fb10c834292803b247a05b6cb7', 7: '48f8ab83e8790d80af628e391f3325ad'}, 'sending': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 5, 5: 5, 6: 5, 7: 5}, 'datetime': {0: pd.Timestamp('2016-11-01 19:13:34'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2016-11-01 10:47:14'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2016-10-31 19:09:21'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2016-11-01 19:13:34'), 4: pd.Timestamp('2016-11-01 11:47:14'), 5: pd.Timestamp('2016-10-31 19:09:20'), 6: pd.Timestamp('2016-10-31 13:42:36'), 7: pd.Timestamp('2016-10-31 10:46:30')}})
print (clicks)
             datetime                              hash  sending
0 2016-11-01 19:13:34  0b1f4745df5925dfb1c8f53a56c43995        5
1 2016-11-01 10:47:14  0a73d5953ebf5826fbb7f3935bad026d        5
2 2016-10-31 19:09:21  605cebbabe0ba1b4248b3c54c280b477        5
3 2016-11-01 19:13:34  0b1f4745df5925dfb1c8f53a56c43995        5
4 2016-11-01 11:47:14  0a73d5953ebf5826fbb7f3935bad026d        5
5 2016-10-31 19:09:20  605cebbabe0ba1b4248b3c54c280b477        5
6 2016-10-31 13:42:36  d26d61fb10c834292803b247a05b6cb7        5
7 2016-10-31 10:46:30  48f8ab83e8790d80af628e391f3325ad        5
```

```
#if column dtype of column datetime is not datetime (with this sample not necessary)
clicks.datetime = pd.to_datetime(clicks.datetime)
clicks['first'] = clicks.groupby(['hash','sending'])['datetime'] \
                        .apply(lambda x: x == x.min()) \
                        .astype(int)
print (clicks)
             datetime                              hash  sending  first
0 2016-11-01 19:13:34  0b1f4745df5925dfb1c8f53a56c43995        5      1
1 2016-11-01 10:47:14  0a73d5953ebf5826fbb7f3935bad026d        5      1
2 2016-10-31 19:09:21  605cebbabe0ba1b4248b3c54c280b477        5      0
3 2016-11-01 19:13:34  0b1f4745df5925dfb1c8f53a56c43995        5      1
4 2016-11-01 11:47:14  0a73d5953ebf5826fbb7f3935bad026d        5      0
5 2016-10-31 19:09:20  605cebbabe0ba1b4248b3c54c280b477        5      1
6 2016-10-31 13:42:36  d26d61fb10c834292803b247a05b6cb7        5      1
7 2016-10-31 10:46:30  48f8ab83e8790d80af628e391f3325ad        5      1
```

----- UPDATE: ------

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.12.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 15.6.0
machine: x86_64
processor: i386
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8

pandas: 0.18.1
```

Comment: Wowza, thanks! I tried the lambda, but didnt make it work, didnt know how to pick the minimum from it.  So that looks good, but still cannot subset it, getting the same error. Although the `clicks.first` is integer finally. Do you know why?

Comment: Maybe there is problem you have duplicated minimal values. It works nice with sample and with real data not?

Comment: there cannot be duplicates per `hash` and `sending`. The error for the subset says: `TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [False] of <type 'bool'>` So it looks like it is not `DataFrame` anymore

Comment: Anf for select is necessary use `clicks['first']` because `first()` is function in pandas

Comment: Thank you. Can you upgrade to last `0.19.1`?

Comment: Omg, I see,I didnt know! It works if I subset as `clicks.ix[clicks['first']==1`!!! Thanks a lot. I need to study up on the `lambda` function.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm not familiar with the pandas module, but I do work with python often (it systems engineering)

Why don't you just use the datetime module? You easily sort them based on the timestamp. For example:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 26 2016, 11:37:25)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M'
>>> timestamps = ['2016-11-01 19:13:34', '2016-11-01 10:47:14',
...               '2016-10-31 19:09:21', '2016-10-31 13:42:36',
...               '2016-10-31 10:46:30']
>>> def compare_dates(d1, d2):
...     d1_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, fmt)
...     d2_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, fmt)
...     if d1 > d2:
...         return 1
...     elif d1 == d2:
...         return 0
...     else:
...         return -1
...
>>> timestamps.sort(cmp=compare_dates)
>>> timestamps
['2016-10-31 10:46:30', '2016-10-31 13:42:36', '2016-10-31 19:09:21', '2016-11-01 10:47:14', '2016-11-01 19:13:34']
>>>
```

As you can see, it's easy to sort dates with the datetime module. Seems trivial to write a comparison function and sort them based on the date to find the earliest occurrence.